# GWT + Hibernate не проходит авторизацию

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, gwt

Асинхронный вызов вызывает onFailure вместо onSuccess, хотя информация поступает, из БД. В чем причина, товарищи?

```
 public class Auth extends Composite {
    interface AuthUiBinder extends UiBinder<HTMLPanel, Auth> {
    }


    @UiField
    TextBox login;
    @UiField
    PasswordTextBox password;
    @UiField
    Button signin;

    private static AuthUiBinder ourUiBinder = GWT.create(AuthUiBinder.class);

    public Auth() {
        initWidget(ourUiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

        signin.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent clickEvent) {

                UserService.App.getInstance().getAllUsers(new AsyncCallback<List<User>>() {
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

                        Window.alert(login.getText() + " " + password.getText());
                    }

                    public void onSuccess(List<User> result) {
                        for (User user: result) {
                            if (login.getText().equals(user.getLogin()) && password.getText().equals(user.getPassword())){
                                History.newItem("greetingUI");
                                RootPanel.get("body").clear();
                                RootPanel.get("body").add(new Greeting(user.getName()));

                            }

                        }
                    }
                });


            }
        });
    }}
```

Лог с консоли

> com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 500 Internal
>   Server Error Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 - Error
>   report
>
> ## 525D76;}--> HTTP Status 500 - com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteService
>
> noshade="noshade">
>
> **type** Exception report
>
> **message**
>   com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteService
>
> **description**
>   The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from
>   fulfilling this request.
>
> **exception**
>
> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteService
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3118)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1340)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1827)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3118)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1340)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1827)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```
>
> **root cause**
>
> ```
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3118)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1340)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1827)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3118)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1340)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1827)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть что происходит в отладчике браузера (что ходит по сети и есть ли ошибки в консоли) и запустить под отладкой серверную часть метода getAllUsers

Comment: @bobzer Приходит 500 код.

Comment: Смотрите логи сервера, если ничего нет - настройте на сервере уровень журналирования DEBUG (обычно по умолчанию установлен уровень  INFO, но некоторые серверные компоненты могут выводить ошибки на уровень DEBUG). Как настроить уровень журналирования - смотрите документацию по вашему серверу приложений.

Comment: @bobzer в описание добавил логи с консоли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убедитесь в том, что в вашем приложении, в папке WEB-INF/lib присутствует библиотека gwt-servlet.jar. Это классы серверной части, требующиеся для корректной работы GWT.

Comment: да, верно. Проблема решена, спасибо. Не знаю почему но добавлял вручную. Мавен не видит эти либы, хоть и в зависимости прописаны. Интересная ситуация.